Does "I hardly knew her." mean "I do not know her"?
From Merriam-Webster

a-> used to emphasize a minimal amount or degree
I hardly knew her. [=I didn't know her well at all.]

In this definition item, I hardly knew her seems to mean "I knew her a little bit.", but they give the equality "I didn't know her well at all". Don't "not...at all" mean "emphasized not"? The explanations and examples they give seem to conflict.

You are leaving out the word "well".  The phrase is "well at all". The dictionary is not giving you bad examples.  well expresses a high degree or extent.

The general understanding of "I hardly knew [her]" would be that you at least knew of her - that perhaps you had some kind of connection - but you did not know the person well. You might say this about a person with whom you had brief exchanges but never any deeper conversation that might help you get to know them well.
Does it mean the same as "I do not know her"? The short answer would be no - most would perceive that to mean you are unaware of the person in question. However, to know someone does mean to have knowledge of them, and in different contexts, sometimes with different spoken inflexion, the word 'know' can be used alone to mean you know a person well, and sometimes that you just have a basic knowledge of their existence. Context is everything.

So, WM's equality 'I didn't know her well at all' does not fit well?

@Mr.Wang there's nothing wrong with that explanation - "not at all well" means not well. You couldn't say that about a person that you did not know at all in any way shape of form. So it still means a minimum degree. I've answered the question in you question title.

The sentence I don’t know Taylor Swift does not normally mean the speaker has never heard of her and has no awareness of her existence. What it does normally mean is that the speaker has never met her, has not made her acquaintance.
It is possible to use that sentence in reply to a suggestion like Given your taste in music, I think you should listen to Taylor Swift. I think you’d really like her. But in that context, the speaker might well add something like though I’ve certainly heard of her. In any event, in that context the name Taylor Swift is being used metonymically to refer not to the artist but to her music.
In any case, I hardly know John typically does imply that the speaker has at least met John but that their acquaintance does not extend much beyond that having met. And  Merriam-Webster has it right.
